# Swagger Codegen Spring Converters

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger(openapi) codegen to generate Rest Api Server Stub.

Is it possible to use the "spring" generator and somehow use Spring Rest converters ?

The problem is that before I had a simple

```
@GetMapping
public String (@RequestBody Locale locale)
```

Now with openapi codegen I have an ugly LocaleDto that has 50 fields and so on. And also I need to manually transform my object back to "Locale" with

```
LocaleUtils.from().
```

Relative docs:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/README.md

Any help is greatly appreciated.